# Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'widget'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using Jquery-ui-multiselect-widget for converting noramal select box to multiselect MultiSelect Widget.
Link for jquery UI pluggin : https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget

HTML :

```
<select id='noOFRows' multiple="multiple" > <option value="10">10<option value="20">20<option value="30">30<option value="40">40<option value="50"> 50 </option> </select>
```

JS code :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#noOFRows").multiselect();    
    });
```

but getting this error.

**Error in Jquery.multiselect.js:**

[image: Error in Jquery.multiselect.js]

**Error in mail index.php**

[image: Error in mail index.php]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are missing [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) library because the widget framework is provided by jQuery UI

If you do not want any other widgets from jQuery UI, then go the the [custom download](http://jqueryui.com/download/) option ans select only `widget` option and download, then add the jquery-ui-xxx.js file to the page after jQuery is included

Comment: then whether the mutli select is added before that or after that?

Comment: multiselect is added at the end.

Answer (score 0):

There was one more case regarding the extensions you installed in your browsers. in some case the add blocker will be the root cause of these errors. In chrome you have "incognito window", make sure it working on that window.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, when you include jQuery UI library, you should make sure that this library is before the multiselect library.

Say:

`<script src="JS/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

`<script src="JS/jquery.multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`